# Poker combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, poker

I have a problem solving the following:

Out of a $52$-card deck, I'm missing all my kings and one card of number $2$. Now if I pull five cards randomly, what is the chance to get $4$ of a kind?

Because I am missing $4$ kings and one card of number $2$, it remains only $11$ out of $13$ values to get $4$ of a kind from. When we have chosen our value, we can choose the last ($5^\text{th}$) card in $11 \times 43 = 473$ different ways (according to the multiplication principle). $11$ is the values that remain and $43$ is the cards that remain after I have pulled $4$ cards. $47$ cards from the start (because I am missing $5$ cards). 
The total of different poker hands is $\displaystyle \binom{47}{5}$ and the probability to get $4$ of a kind is therefore

$$(11 \times 43) \div \dfrac{47 \times 46 \times 45 \times 44 \times 43}{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5} = \frac{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 11}{47 \times 46 \times 45 \times 44} = \frac{1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 11}{47 \times (2 \times 23) \times (5 \times 3 \times 3) \times (4 \times 11)} = \frac{1}{47 \times 23 \times 3} = 0,0003 = 0,03 \%$$

Is this a correct calculation?

Also if I would drop one more card, which card should I drop to maximize my chances so that $5$ randomly cards give $4$ of a kind?

Directly, I would say that I could drop one more of the number $2$ because from the begging I only had $3$ cards of the number $2$ and therefore I could not get any $4$ of a kind from number $2$ anyways. Is it correct or should I think otherwise?

I am thankful for any tips and advice.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial where you can learn to typeset equations and formulae.

Comment: Your calculations are reasoning seem fine. I would encourage you to invest some time in learning the rudiments of TeX, to make your mathematical expressions easier to read. For example, turning "1/47*23*3=0.0003" to "{1\over47\cdot23\cdot3}=0.0003" and putting it inside dollar signs produces ${1\over47\cdot23\cdot3}=0.0003$.  An extra dollar sign on either side displays it as $${1\over47\cdot23\cdot3}=0.0003$$

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks for the tips! I know that my expressions may feel a little hard to read. I am new to StackExchange but I will absolutely take some time and learn TeX.

Comment: @Sam Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach and results are correct.

Comment: Alright! But how does it come that of a normal 52-card deck the chance is lower that you get for of a kind. The chance is 0.025 for a normal 52-card deck and for mine it is 0.03%. I cant figure out the logic.

Comment: @Leon: Removing one $2$ makes no difference. Since the problem is invariant under permutations of the ranks and the suits, we can assume without loss of generality that the first card drawn is the $2$ of diamonds, which shows that the proportion of fours-of-a-kind is the same among the hands that include the $2$ of diamonds as it is overall, so removing all hands that include the $2$ of diamonds doesn't change the chances of getting four of a kind. You can see that removing all $4$ kings increases the chances by imagining that you continue removing entire ranks until only two are left.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now I see the logic.